# Getting directions between two points in google maps iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, nsurlsession

I have the following code to get the path between two points in Google maps iOS SDK. However, I am not receiving any data back or any errors even.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(latitude),\(longitude)&destination=\(finallat),\(finallong)&key=**************")
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in
    if let data = data {
        do {
            // Convert the data to JSON
            let jsonSerialized = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any]

            if let json = jsonSerialized, let url = json["url"], let explanation = json["explanation"] {
                print(url)
                print(explanation)
            }
        }  catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    } else if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't do anything with the `dataTask` so it isn't actually being called. You need to call `resume()`.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(latitude),\(longitude)&destination=\(finallat),\(finallong)&key=**************")
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in
    if let data = data {
        do {
            // Convert the data to JSON
            let jsonSerialized = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any]

            if let json = jsonSerialized, let url = json["url"], let explanation = json["explanation"] {
                print(url)
                print(explanation)
            }
        }  catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    } else if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
task.resume()
```